# Windows Authentication via LDAP in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am beginner with mvc3 and i and i have created an internet application for which i need to apply windows authentication and check for the user roles in the AD. Is that possible with LDAP? I have searched online but nothing seems clear. Hence, request you guys to assist or post some links which have clear explanation of the procedure to be followed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably a question for http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

It is possible,

Have a look at this [URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.  There are many samples of this online.

In your web.config add the LDAP connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://what ever it is" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Also add the following:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="15" slidingExpiration="false" protection="All" />
</authentication>

<membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
     <providers>
          <clear />
          <add name="ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
     </providers>
</membership>
```

The rest should work the same as normal SQL membership:

```
public ActionResult LogOn()
{
     return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnViewModel viewModel, string returnUrl)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          if (Membership.ValidateUser(viewModel.UserName, viewModel.Password))
          {
          }
     }
}

Your LogOnViewModel:

public class LogOnViewModel
{
     public string UserName { get; set; }

     public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I hope this can help you in the right direction.